# Reload Webview android

Tags: android, webview

I have a Asynctask which retrieves some data from the remote server like...

```
public void doInBackground(String...params) {

//does some process and store obtained data in Shared Preferences 
}
```

**----------
**layout.xml***
-----------*

```
 <customWebview attr1="somevalue"/>
```

---

**customWebview class**

---

I have customWebview class which initialize some values in constructor of the class and display the content using 
    customWebView.loadurl("someurl")//

Here the problem is..,we get data that contain values to initialize customWebview from the asynctask...

Initially...Custom Web View loads with some default data...

I need to reinitialize only those customwebviews in the layout with the values obtained from AsyncTask...(Reload only customwebviews not the whole layout or activity)

Please guide me through this....

Answer (score 0):

You can give your custom webview an id in the XML, then use `findViewById(id)` and set the values on it. if you have the public methods defined for your values, you can change them from inside the AsyncTask, then call `loadData()` from `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Here the problem is...i cannot set using id because id can be changed..i cannot restrict id to be same in xml and code...

Comment: why does the id of the view have to change?